# Existence of a period three cycle for a continuous unimodal interval map (A question related to Li-Yorke theorem)

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous unimodal map from a closed interval $I$ to itself. Suppose that there exist $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4\in I$ such that $f(x_1)=x_2$, $f(x_2)=x_3$, $f(x_3)=x_4$, and $x_4<x_1<x_2<x_3$. Then is it true that $f$ has a period three cycle? Some posts (and corresponding answers) suggested to use the intermediate value theorem for $g(x)=f^3(x)-x$. However, a zero of $g$ is either a point of period 3 for $f$ or a fixed point of $f$. I do not see how to proceed if we get a fixed point.

Comment: You need to consider the sub-interval that you find the period-3 candidate in. It should be obvious by construction that the image of that interval is disjoint from it so that a simple fixed point can not be there.

Comment: Another issue is about using the intermediate value theorem. We have $g(x_1)=f^3(x_1)-x_1=x_4-x_1<0$ and $g(x_2)=f^3(x_2)-x_2=f(x_4)-x_2<0$. The last inequality follows from the unimodality of $f$. Since $g(x_1)<0$ and $g(x_2)<0$, we cannot use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check consequences on intervals:

- The maximum of $f$ is after $x_2$, so $f([x_1,x_2])=[x_2,x_3]$.
- The image of an interval contains at least the interval between the values at the endpoints, so $f([x_2,x_3])\supset [x_4,x_3]\supset [x_1,x_3]$.
- The maximizer $c$, $f(c)>x_3$, is inside $[x_2,x_3]$, otherwise $f(x_3)=x_4<x_3=f(x_2)$ is not possible (remember unimodal).

As a consequence there is an interval $J\subset [c,x_3]$ with
$$
f(J)=[x_1,x_2], ~~ f^2(J)=[x_2,x_3], ~~ f^3(J)\supset J.
$$
and $f^3$ restricted to $J$ is falling. This is sufficient to find a fixed point $x_*$. As $x_*\in[c,x_3]$ and $f(x_*)\in[x_1,x_2]$, this is not a fixed point of $f$, thus a true period-3 point.

---

To be a bit more correct and independent of the location of the maximum, the interval $[x_2,x_3]$ contains a segment where $f$ is falling. The image of that segment contains the interval $[x_1,x_2]$. Let $a<b$ inside that segment be the points with $f(a)=x_2$ and $f(b)=x_1$. Then
$$
f^2(a)=x_3, ~~ f^3(a)=x_4<x_2<a\\
f^2(b)=x_2, ~~ f^3(b)=x_3>b
$$
The interval $[a,b]$ satisfies the assumptions of the intermediate value theorem for $g$.

Comment: Thanks Lutz for your answer. I do not understand what you mean by "$f^3$ restricted to $J$ is falling". Do you mean that $f^3$ restricted to $J$ is decreasing on $J$? If so, how to see it? Also, why that gives a fixed point for $f^3$?

Comment: When I wrote that I was thinking that the first two $f$ are increasing over their restricted domain, and the last decreasing, or some variation thereof, so that in total one gets decreasing. But that might not be necessary. It is sufficient if one can show that the interval end points end up under $f^3$ above and below $J$. But I did not check that yet.